# Solar Panel (5v/500mAh) charging USB Power bank (5v/1a)

Tags: power-supply, dc, solar-cell, charger

I've been trying to find information on this but haven't found an accurate answer.

I have a USB Power Bank that has a max charging input of 5v/1a and a 5v/500mAh solar panel that can output up to 5-6v.  Since the USB Power Bank already has a regulator built in, is it possible to just directly connect the small panel directly into the power bank?

I'd imagine I don't need a regulator since one already exists, but maybe something to cut off if the power is too low?

Comment: The regulator (not regular) boosts its battery (3.7V) UP to 5V, not an external input DOWN to 5V. The power bank expects clean 5V from an US port while charging. Running it from the solar panel relies on the solar panel being too weak to over-volt the charging input. Not a very good idea.

Comment: A 5v/1a solar regulator into the power bank should be sufficient then, correct? And I'm assuming 500mAh would be sufficient to charge (at 2-5x slower, but would work).

Comment: Yes to a suitable regulator, and yes to slower charging at reduced current.